# Installing Apache2 for Ubuntu 20.04 using Specific Version between v2.4.32 to v2.4.44 (exclusive)

Tags: server, package-management, system-installation, apache2, php

I've recently been trying to test out a vulnerability in Apache Webserver that requires a very specific version of Apache2 and its related libfiles. (Specifically, libapache2-uwsgi versions in the range v2.4.32 to v2.4.44 are vulnerable to this publicly listed exploit. I wish to test it.

I've been trying out two different methods of getting apache to work properly, and thusfar have not been able to get it working either way.

### Method 1:

My problem is, whilst I have managed to find the Launchpad for these version (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2) - Specifically version 2.4.41.

[Problem 1: What architecture does Ubuntu use when virtualized with Virtual Box?]

Through this, I've been downloading the .deb files for everything there. Unfortunately, I've been unable to install it using **dpkg** due to dependency problems (the deb files relate to each other in a way I personally don't know).
This is as far as I have gotten in this method.

### Method 2

Through (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html), I have also been attempting to compile and install Apache via httpd method.
After many hours of debug on AskUbuntu and similar, I found about needing APR, APR-Utils and PCRE sources in **/httpd/srclib/** and acted to put them there.

[Problem 2: During make, I get an error stating:

```
ab.c:(.text+0x6228): undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
/usr/bin/ld: ab.c:(.text+0x625f): undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method'
/usr/bin/ld: ab.c:(.text+0x6509): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_malloc_init'
```

Unfortunately, unlike in [this Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856812/apache-2-4-1-undefined-reference-to-sslv2-client-method) or [this reference](https://9to5answer.com/apache-2-4-1-undefined-reference-to-sslv2_client_method-39), the  `/usr/local/php-5.5.3/` folder doesn't exist.]

Any help on either of these methods would be massive help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this info about php 5. https://www.digitalcanvas.com/blog/is-php-5-6-still-supported/

Comment: Why not install from a tar ball in /opt? it will have all dependencies already fixed. Same can be done for php or any other tool you need: set it up in /opt and connect it to eachother. Then start apache from /opt/ using your current sites-enabled. "Problem 1: What architecture does Ubuntu use when virtualized with Virtual Box?" whatever you tell VBox to use. VBox likely defaults to what the system itself uses though.

Comment: When very specific versions of packages are required, I have found the only reliable way to do this is via Docker containers. [From here you can get Apache 2.4.41](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/tags?page=1&name=2.4.41) and, if you are going to test for Log4Shell or Text4Shell, these containers may be vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @matigo - I'll try docker as it seems easiest, but thanks for the answers to the other part Rinzwind. That clears up some confusion.

Comment: I am having a trouble with docker however - I can't seem to configure a module proxy through the dockerfile and I can't seem to grab it with copy as per `"docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf"` - the httpd.conf grab works in this case, but not for `/usr/local/apache2/conf/conf.d/mod_proxy.conf` @matigo